# Sort array into an object with key and value pairs with same values being pushed into the same key/value

Tags: javascript, lodash

I would like to sort an array into and object with key value pairs.

So if I had an array like this [1,2,3,2,4,1,5,1,6] it should spit out something like this. I was trying to use lodash for it!

```
{
  1: [1, 1, 1],
  2: [2, 2],
  3: [3],
  4: [4],
  5: [5],
  6: [6]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and return object.

```js
var ar = [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 5, 1, 6];
var result = ar.reduce(function(o, e) {
  o[e] = (o[e] || []).concat(e);
  return o;
}, {});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Some basic iteration would do that, where you either set an array, or push to an existing array

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,2,4,1,5,1,6];
var obj = {};

arr.forEach( (x) => x in obj ? obj[x].push(x) : obj[x] = [x]);

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>'+ JSON.stringify(obj, 0, 4) +'</pre>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple pure JavaScript version to achieve this (https://jsfiddle.net/azkuodyc/)

```
var array = [1,2,3,2,4,1,5,1,6];
var newArrayObject = {};

for (key in array) {
    var value = array[key];
    if (typeof newArrayObject[key] == 'undefined') {
        newArrayObject[key] = [];
    }
    newArrayObject[key].push(value);
}
```

Comment: there is no assignment in this declaration `var newArrayObject[key].push(value)`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,2,4,1,5,1,6];
const r = {};

arr.forEach(e=>r[e]?r[e].push(e):r[e]=[e]);

console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

One other way of doing this is;

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,2,4,1,5,1,6],
    obj = arr.reduce((p,c) => (p[c] = p[c] ? p[c].concat(c) : [c],p),{});
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr =  [1,2,3,2,4,1,5,1,6];

var res = _(arr).countBy().mapValues((value, key) => {
  return _.times(value, _.constant(parseInt(key)));
}).value();

console.log(res);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7bppaxx5/